# WebView loadDataWithbaseURL java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, webview

```
//. . .

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //. . .

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        //. . .
        mainActivityProcedure ( );
    }

    //. . .

    public static void mainActivityProcedure ( ) {
        //. . .
        AnotherActivity.anotherActivityProcedure ( ) ;
        SomeActivity.someActivityProcedure ( );
        //. . .
    }

    //. . .

}

//. . .

public class SomeActivity extends Activity {

    //. . .

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        //. . .
        someWebView = ( WebView ) findViewById ( R.id.someWebView );
        //. . .
    }

    //. . .

    public static void someActivityProcedure ( ) {
        //. . .
        try {
            someWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL ( null , someHTMLCode, mimeType, encoding, null );
    catch ( Exception e ) {
        Log.i("SomeActivity", "someWebView loadDataBaseURL () " + e.toString() );
    }
        //. . .
    }

    //. . .
}

//. . .

public class AnotherActivity extends Activity {

    //. . .

    @Override
    protected void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        //. . .
        anotherWebView = ( WebView ) findViewById ( R . id.anotherWebView ) ;
        //. . .
    }

    //. . .

    public static void anotherActivityProcedure ( ) {
        //. . .
        anotherWebView . loadDataWithBaseURL ( null, anotherHTMLCode, mimeType, encoding, null ) ;
        //. . .
    }
}
```

AnotherActivity always loads anotherHTMLCode, when anotherActivityProcedure calls.
SomeActivity loads someHTMLCode except when mainActivityProcedure calls from MainActivity.onCreate.
What's wrong with someWebView or SomeActivity?
I cant put here original code.

Addition: Replacin` null in loadDataWithBaseURL() not fix it.
Addition: Logcat shows message java.lang.NullPointerException that puts Log.i() from catch.

Comment: Post your log cat trace

Comment: Logcat shows java.lang.NullPointerException that thrown by someWebView

Comment: It is hard to identify your issue without logcat trace and code

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Initilized SomeActivity inside MainActivity and the use _someactivity object you can access.

```
SomeActivity _someactivity = new SomeActivity();
_someactivity.someActivityProcedure ();
```

Comment: someWebView trows NullPointerException

Comment: Sorry, someWebView throws NullPointerException